# Run php code in .html file

Tags: apache2, php7

I have ubuntu 16.0.4 on vps. I can't run php code from a html file. 
i add a .htaccess file with this code:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .html .htm
```

and on /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php7.0.conf this code:

```
<FilesMatch ".+\.html$">
 SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

Any suggestions, because the code don't run. If i put .php file is working.
The php code on index.html is:

```
<?php echo "Hello"; ?>
```

Comment: [This may help you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39396325/1810128), notice the different regex and all the note about AllowOverride

Comment: [this one is different](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6295204/1810128) , it uses different directives.

Comment: <FilesMatch "\.html$"> would work better.

Comment: '<FilesMatch "\.html$"> would work better.' This code worked. After you add the code restart the apache and works.

Comment: Or execute "sudo apache2ctl graceful"